# Apache Camel Timer - FixedRate true causing duplicate calls

Tags: apache, timer, duplicates, apache-camel

```
<route>
 <from uri="timer://SomeTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=60000" />
  <to uri="seda:SomeProcessor" />
</route>
<route>
  <from uri="seda:SomeProcessor" />
  <setHeader headerName="ServiceName">
<constant>SomeService</constant>
   </setHeader>
  <to uri="bean:serviceConsumer?method=callService" />          
</route>
```

it intern calls a procedure which is supposed to Poll and then inert some data in a table. Its duplicating intermittently in the target table and we can see the sqlid is separate for the duplicate rows inserted. Lately the DB is performing badly and taking a lot of time.

I am thinking FixedRate=true is making timer objects bunching up and then firing rapidly creating a race condition to duplicate data. Can anyone advice please.

Comment: This is a very confusing question!

Comment: Are you saying that if your service is called a second time, it may not work correctly if it has not yet completed processing the first call? If so, you can try making your service atomic. e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125117/concurrent-process-inserting-data-in-database